# How to Handle Lighting from a 3D Game Engine with a Roguelike Game using Shadowcasting

Tags: unity, lighting, roguelikes

Normally the shadowcasting will, from the player position, set a brightness amount to each relevant tile. Yet I'm making a roguelike with a 3D map, and Unity has lighting.

Currently I have the player piece with a point light, and game objects that haven't been seen yet are set to inactive. but it doesn't have the same effect.

Has anyone resolved this situation?  Any suggestions?

Addendum:
Screen shots:
[image: example start of gameplay screen]

[image: example gameplay screen after movement]

I somewhat like the effect as it is in the screenshots; I'd like to be able to control the amount of light in each 'tile' if possible.

Comment: It might help to add some images to this question - say an example of what you have now, and an example or mock-up of how you want it to look instead.

Comment: seems like the light passes through the walls -- might a collider solve that?

Comment: No, but placing a shadowcasting renderer in the wall, and enabling shadows on the light, will.